# Dry-er Way of Writing a Bunch of If Else Statements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, dry

I have a variable `placement` that can be set to the following values: top, top-left, top-right, bottom, bottom-left, bottom-right, right, right-top, right-bottom, left, left-top, left-bottom.

I have another variable `const trigger = triggerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();` so I can determine where the trigger element is, and based on that, set the `placement` variable accordingly.

I am currently using a lot of `if else` statements. For instance:

```
if (placement === "top" && trigger.top < 75 && windowWidth - trigger.right > 75 && trigger.left > 175) 
  { placement = "bottom";
} else if ( placement === "top" && windowWidth - trigger.right < 75 &&  windowHeight - trigger.bottom > 75 && trigger.top < 75) 
  { placement = "left-top"; }

...and the code goes on and on
```

What's a "DRY-er" way of doing this?

Comment: Instead of repeating parts of the if statement every time, you could split it up into multiple nested if statements. Also instead of repeating stuff like `windowWidth - trigger.right > 75`, save that in a variable first. It'll make the conditions easier to read.

Comment: why not use the [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) API?

Comment: If you know it needs to less repetitive why not try something yourself?

Comment: You could just set a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) or prop value on each element specifing which value it represents and retrieve that value instead of trying to determine the elements position, eg `<MyElement place="top-left" />`

Comment: Please post the whole code. From just the first two statements, we cannot find the pattern. (Surely, there is a pattern, right?) Try describing the pattern in words if you can. Then describe it in code.

Answer (score 0):

Consolidate the logic in these tests and only check once. Assign a variable if instead of repeating the same calculations:

```
if (placement === "top" && trigger.top < 75 ) {
    const triggerFromWidth = windowWidth - trigger.right;
    if (triggerFromWidth > 75 && trigger.left > 175) { 
      placement = "bottom";
    } else if (triggerFromWidth < 75 && windowHeight - trigger.bottom > 75) { 
      placement = "left-top"; 
    }
}
```